# Is shutdown.exe necessary to shutdown Windows?

Tags: windows

Is the file `C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe` necessary to shutdown or restart Windows?

Comment: Try renaming it something else and see.

Comment: @martineau Who risks to even rename a system 32 file!

Comment: @MukulKumar Someone who wants to find out the effect, and knows that they can very easily reverse it?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I use `Task Manager` to automate my computer shut down every night, but for some reason, despite the `shutdown.exe` call, my computer never does shut down, only the opening of the Command Line dialog, and immediately closing. Perhaps some error is being caught, but I can't glimpse the log fast enough.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: You need to issue `shutdown -s -t 0` - a plain `shutdown` only displays help.

Comment: What do you mean `display help`? And thanks -- I'll need to remember to add those arguments tonight!

Comment: In windows 9x you can use `C:\Windows\RUNDLL32.EXE user,exitwindows` to shutdown. Not sure if it runs in win XP and above

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Open up a command prompt on your system, then just type `shutdown` with no arguments.  You'll see what I mean.  It displays usage info for the `shutdown` command.

Comment: Unplugging the computer should shut it off, regardless of any file's name.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: "Shut off" and "shut down" are not the same thing, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - You're saying that unplugging a (non-battery-powered) PC wouldn't shut it down?  (No one said anything about a "clean" shutdown.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Shutdown means "clean" shutdown. It's implicit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My mother strongly disagrees -- which is probably why she's always calling me about computer problems.

Comment: @MukulKumar If you're too worried then this is a perfect use for virtualisation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your question of course originates from your answer at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24011/18907 , in particular from `kinokijuf`'s comment upon the initial revision of your answer.

As `kinokijuf` said, Windows is not Unix.  On Unices and Linux, `shutdown` is indeed involved in the full shutdown process.  It is the program that sends regular warning messages to logged-in users and that writes the `/run/nologin` file to prevent further logging-on a short while before the scheduled shutdown time.

On Windows NT, this is not the case.

The "Shut down" action on the "power button" on the Windows Explorer Start menu, the "Shutdown" menu option in Task Manager, `REBOOT /S` in TCC or Take Command, and other applications programs that allow you to shut the system down all initiate shutdown by directly calling one of two Win32 API calls: `InitiateSystemShutdownEx()` or `ExitWindowsEx()`.  They don't do things indirectly by running the `shutdown` program.  (That actually needs more code to do than just calling the Win32 API call.)  The `shutdown` program, when one is doing a local shutdown, calls those same Win32 API calls too.

It's actually `winlogon`, `csrss`, and `smss` that are the programs that shut down Windows NT.  In particular, it is `winlogon` that does the main work of processing deferred shutdown requests.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [*The Windows NT 6 shutdown process*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- [`shutdown`](http://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?shutdown(8)).  *FreeBSD 9.2 manual pages*.  2013-03-19.
- [`shutdown`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/shutdown.html).  *`systemd` manual pages*.  2013.  Freedesktop.org.
- [`shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/shutdown.8.html).  *`upstart` manual pages*.  2009.  Canonical Ltd.
- [`InitiateSystemShutdownEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa376874(v=vs.85).aspx).  MSDN.  Microsoft corporation.
- [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx).  MSDN.  Microsoft corporation.
- [`REBOOT`](http://jpsoft.com/help/reboot.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.  JP Software.

Comment: You are truly a sensible answerer! I liked the way you traced back to the real situation through my profile.

Comment: Note that on Linux systems, the `shutdown` command is not at all involved in the full shutdown process; while it may send warning messages or touch /run/nologin, all it does in regard to actually shutting down is to send the appropriate command to systemd, init, etc., and exit. The init process or its modern replacement systemd actually does the work of shutting down the system.

Comment: No, M. Hampton, sending the messages and stopping logons is a fully-fledged part of the full shutdown procedure. Don't go thinking that it has magically gone away with Linux. The manual pages for two Linux `shutdown`s are right in front of you. Thinking that is as wrong as the nonsense in the _Introduction to Linux_ at TLDP which says that "UNIX is not made to be shut down". UNIX was indeed made to be shut down, and there are quite a lot of books over the past 40 years for UNIX professionals that cover the full procedure, with warning messages to users as step #1.

Comment: There are even books for Linux professionals. I'd plug Rod Smith's _LPIC Study Guide_, which has `shutdown` on page 22, but it's not in my library. Sorry, M. Smith. (-: My library has the likes of Coffin's _SVR5 Reference_ (the warning users step described on pages 355 and 683), a _SCO UNIX System Administrator's Guide_ (warnings to users as shutdown first step on pages 52–53), and even Fielder's/Hunter's _UNIX System Administration_ (the whole of chapter 6 is about shutdown, with warning users at the beginning of the chapter). One can find many more books for professionals covering this.

Answer (score 55):

No.

Explorer doesn't call this command when you shut down from the Start menu.

Shutting down the system is possible with a Win32 API call (@JdeBP's answer provides great details on that if interested). The command is just a convenient way to do it from a script, scheduled task, or the Run dialog.

Comment: Actually, `shutdown.exe` does not even do a graceful shutdown.

Comment: Careful with that answer! Explorer doesn't call that command, but other processes that shut down or restart windows do: and it's not just 'a convenient way to do it' if the script or scheduled task is an installer or a scheduled maintenance task from your sysadmin.

Comment: That doesn't make it "necessary", Nile. See the context of the question (which isn't in the question, but is in my answer and what is pointed to there) for the rebuttal that the questioner was questioning, and the statement about `shutdown` that the questioner originally made.  (These parts of) installers are often written in compiled languages that just call the Win32 API, by the way.

Answer (score 8):

As explained by ultrasawblade (upvote), the system shutdown is a Win32 API call to:  [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The link also has an example on how to implement a shutdown from C.  Also, you can do it from C# using P/Invoke (Platform Invoke).  pinvoke.net has a bunch of signatures available for use:http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/exitwindowsex.html

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary. [`shutdown.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) is just a utility to shut down a local or remote computer. It looks like `shutdown.exe` uses the [Native API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API)'s [`NtShutdownsystem`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/Hardware/NtShutdownSystem.html). While Windows uses [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([as already mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).